# Why is there no module named queue in PyPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

I need to use PyPy because speed is of the essence. I want to use priority queue and normally with Python I'd use `queue` module but PyPy gives me an error.

```
import queue
```

error:

```
import queue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

Why is this module not available? I thought that PyPy is compatible with Python's standard library.

Comment: Something's wrong with your PyPy setup. (Also you should use `heapq` instead of `queue` - the `queue` module's classes are specifically designed to be used as inter-thread message passing systems, and they have design choices and overhead that make them awkward and inefficient for single-threaded use.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thank you, it works now. I didn't know that `queue` has such usage.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, how can pop the biggest element from queue using heapq?

Comment: The `queue` module is fine and exists on PyPy like CPython.  Maybe you're comparing CPython 3.x with PyPy 2.x?  The standard library has a module named `Queue` on Python 2.x which has been renamed to `queue` on Python 3.x.

Comment: I compare the newest pypy to CPython3

Comment: @Karol: PyPy3.6 v7.3.1 or PyPy 7.3.1? (Also if you want a max heap, wrap the elements in a class that reverses the comparison order, just like you would with `queue.PriorityQueue`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user2357112supportsMonica I have the solution. Just use `heapq`.